# How to count merged values using reduce()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, reduce

I have a list of four data frames and want to merge them all in one table based on common column ('id') and then count these merged rows. I thought I could do this by using `reduce()` and `lambda` expression something like this:

```
number_of_rows = reduce(lambda a, b: a['id'].isin(b['id']).value_counts(), list_of_dataframes)
```

But of course it doesn't work. My problem is I don't know how to write a code that will add number of common rows from first pair of value_counts() functions to next pair. Thanks in advance!

List of dataframes:

```
list_of_df = [df_hops, df_method_mash_temp, df_ingredients_malt, whole_table]
```

Each dataframe:

df_hops:

```
|    |   hops.name     | hops.add  | hops.attribute  | hops.amount.value  | hops.amount.unit  | id  |                name                 |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----+-------------------------------------+
| 0  | Fuggles         | start     | bitter          |             25.00  | grams             |  1  | Buzz                                |
| 1  | First Gold      | start     | bitter          |             25.00  | grams             |  1  | Buzz                                |
| 2  | Fuggles         | middle    | flavour         |             37.50  | grams             |  1  | Buzz                                |
| 3  | First Gold      | middle    | flavour         |             37.50  | grams             |  1  | Buzz                                |
| 4  | Cascade         | end       | flavour         |             37.50  | grams             |  1  | Buzz                                |
| 5  | Amarillo        | start     | bitter          |             13.80  | grams             |  2  | Trashy Blonde                       |
| 6  | Simcoe          | start     | bitter          |             13.80  | grams             |  2  | Trashy Blonde                       |
| 7  | Amarillo        | end       | flavour         |             26.30  | grams             |  2  | Trashy Blonde                       |
| 8  | Motueka         | end       | flavour         |             18.80  | grams             |  2  | Trashy Blonde                       |
| 9  | Bramling Cross  | middle    | bitter          |             10.00  | grams             |  3  | Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----+-------------------------------------+
```

df_method_mash_temp:

```
|    | method.mash_temp.duration  | method.mash_temp.temp.value  | method.mash_temp.temp.unit  | id  |                name                 |
+----+----------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----+-------------------------------------+
| 0  | 75.0                       |                        64.0  | celsius                     |  1  | Buzz                                |
| 1  | NaN                        |                        69.0  | celsius                     |  2  | Trashy Blonde                       |
| 2  | 10.0                       |                        60.0  | celsius                     |  3  | Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides |
| 3  | 30.0                       |                        65.0  | celsius                     |  3  | Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides |
+----+----------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----+-------------------------------------+
```

df_ingredients_malt:

```
|    | ingredients.malt.name   | ingredients.malt.amount.value  | ingredients.malt.amount.unit  | id  |                name                 |
+----+-------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----+-------------------------------------+
| 0  | Maris Otter Extra Pale  |                       3.30000  | kilograms                     |  1  | Buzz                                |
| 1  | Caramalt                |                       0.20000  | kilograms                     |  1  | Buzz                                |
| 2  | Munich                  |                       0.40000  | kilograms                     |  1  | Buzz                                |
| 3  | Maris Otter Extra Pale  |                       3.25000  | kilograms                     |  2  | Trashy Blonde                       |
| 4  | Caramalt                |                       0.20000  | kilograms                     |  2  | Trashy Blonde                       |
| 5  | Munich                  |                       0.40000  | kilograms                     |  2  | Trashy Blonde                       |
| 6  | Propino Pale Malt       |                       1.63000  | kilograms                     |  3  | Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides |
+----+-------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----+-------------------------------------+
```

whole_table (This is the main table from which the other three above come from):

```
|    | id  |                name                  |             tagline               | first_brewed  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                          description                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |               image_url                | abv   | ibu   | target_fg  | target_og  | ebc   |  srm   | ph   | attenuation_level  |                                                    food_pairing                                                      |                                                                                      brewers_tips                                                                                       |     contributed_by      | volume.value  | volume.unit  | boil_volume.value  | boil_volume.unit  |                                                                                                                method.mash_temp                                                                                                                  | method.fermentation.temp.value  | method.fermentation.temp.unit  |                                              method.twist                                                |                                                                                                                                                                     ingredients.malt                                                                                                                                                                       |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ingredients.hops                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |      ingredients.yeast      |
+----+-----+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-------+-------+------------+------------+-------+--------+------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 0  |  1  | Buzz                                 | A Real Bitter Experience.         | 09/2007       | A light, crisp and bitter IPA brewed with English and American hops. A small batch brewed only once.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png  | 4.50  | 60.0  |    1010.0  |    1044.0  | 20.0  | 10.00  | 4.4  |             75.00  | [Spicy chicken tikka masala, Grilled chicken quesadilla, Caramel toffee cake]                                        | The earthy and floral aromas from the hops can be overpowering. Drop a little Cascade in at the end of the boil to lift the profile with a bit of citrus.                               | Sam Mason <samjbmason>  |           20  | litres       |                25  | litres            | [{'temp': {'value': 64, 'unit': 'celsius'}, 'duration': 75}]                                                                                                                                                                                     |                           19.0  | celsius                        | None                                                                                                     | [{'name': 'Maris Otter Extra Pale', 'amount': {'value': 3.3, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Caramalt', 'amount': {'value': 0.2, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Munich', 'amount': {'value': 0.4, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}]                                                                                                                                | [{'name': 'Fuggles', 'amount': {'value': 25, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'start', 'attribute': 'bitter'}, {'name': 'First Gold', 'amount': {'value': 25, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'start', 'attribute': 'bitter'}, {'name': 'Fuggles', 'amount': {'value': 37.5, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'middle', 'attribute': 'flavour'}, {'name': 'First Gold', 'amount': {'value': 37.5, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'middle', 'attribute': 'flavour'}, {'name': 'Cascade', 'amount': {'value': 37.5, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'end', 'attribute': 'flavour'}]  | Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™ |
| 1  |  2  | Trashy Blonde                        | You Know You Shouldn't            | 04/2008       | A titillating, neurotic, peroxide punk of a Pale Ale. Combining attitude, style, substance, and a little bit of low self esteem for good measure; what would your mother say? The seductive lure of the sassy passion fruit hop proves too much to resist. All that is even before we get onto the fact that there are no additives, preservatives, pasteurization or strings attached. All wrapped up with the customary BrewDog bite and imaginative twist.  | https://images.punkapi.com/v2/2.png    | 4.10  | 41.5  |    1010.0  |    1041.7  | 15.0  | 15.00  | 4.4  |             76.00  | [Fresh crab with lemon, Garlic butter dipping sauce, Goats cheese salad, Creamy lemon bar doused in powdered sugar]  | Be careful not to collect too much wort from the mash. Once the sugars are all washed out there are some very unpleasant grainy tasting compounds that can be extracted into the wort.  | Sam Mason <samjbmason>  |           20  | litres       |                25  | litres            | [{'temp': {'value': 69, 'unit': 'celsius'}, 'duration': None}]                                                                                                                                                                                   |                           18.0  | celsius                        | None                                                                                                     | [{'name': 'Maris Otter Extra Pale', 'amount': {'value': 3.25, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Caramalt', 'amount': {'value': 0.2, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Munich', 'amount': {'value': 0.4, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}]                                                                                                                               | [{'name': 'Amarillo', 'amount': {'value': 13.8, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'start', 'attribute': 'bitter'}, {'name': 'Simcoe', 'amount': {'value': 13.8, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'start', 'attribute': 'bitter'}, {'name': 'Amarillo', 'amount': {'value': 26.3, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'end', 'attribute': 'flavour'}, {'name': 'Motueka', 'amount': {'value': 18.8, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'end', 'attribute': 'flavour'}]                                                                                                                | Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™ |
| 2  |  3  | Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides  | Japanese Citrus Berliner Weisse.  | 11/2015       | Japanese citrus fruit intensifies the sour nature of this German classic.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | https://images.punkapi.com/v2/keg.png  | 4.20  |  8.0  |    1007.0  |    1040.0  |  8.0  |  4.00  | 3.2  |             83.00  | [Smoked chicken wings, Miso ramen, Yuzu cheesecake]                                                                  | Clean everything twice. All you want is the clean sourness of lactobacillus.                                                                                                            | Sam Mason <samjbmason>  |           20  | litres       |                25  | litres            | [{'temp': {'value': 60, 'unit': 'celsius'}, 'duration': 10}, {'temp': {'value': 65, 'unit': 'celsius'}, 'duration': 30}, {'temp': {'value': 72, 'unit': 'celsius'}, 'duration': 10}, {'temp': {'value': 78, 'unit': 'celsius'}, 'duration': 5}]  |                           21.0  | celsius                        | Soured naturally using the kettle souring technique, Yuzu fruit: 50g at middle, Yuzu juice: 200ml at FV  | [{'name': 'Propino Pale Malt', 'amount': {'value': 1.63, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Wheat Malt', 'amount': {'value': 1.63, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Propino Pale Malt for kettle souring', 'amount': {'value': 0.03, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}, {'name': 'Acidulated Malt for kettle souring', 'amount': {'value': 0.03, 'unit': 'kilograms'}}]  | [{'name': 'Bramling Cross', 'amount': {'value': 10, 'unit': 'grams'}, 'add': 'middle', 'attribute': 'bitter'}]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™ |
+----+-----+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-------+-------+------------+------------+-------+--------+------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

@Anshul:

```
list_of_df = [df_hops,df_method_mash_temp,df_ingredients_malt,whole_table]

merged_count = 0

def merge_dfs(df_a, df_b):
    df = df_a.merge(df_b, on=['id', 'name'], how='outer')

    global merged_count
    merged_count += df_a.shape[0] + df_b.shape[0] - df.shape[0]
    return df

# use reduce function to get the final merged dataframe
df_final = reduce(merge_dfs, list_of_df)

print(merged_count)
```

The rest of my code are requests from API and simple normalizations made in order to create tables you see above. I don't think it is needed to paste here in context of this question but if you want me to post it here just write and I will do this.

Comment: kindly share small samples of ur data, with ur expected output

Comment: Make  your accumulator a tuple: `(List[pd.DataFrame], int)` with initial values of `(init_df_list, 0)` and make your monoidal op a lambda which both merges and increments.

Comment: Could you explain in more plain way? It would be nice if you tell me more based on my tables.

Answer (score 0):

I got curious and wanted to try this out. I created my own set of sample dataframes, implemented merging the dataframes using 'reduce', use a 'global' variable to get the total count of rows that got merged. This is what I did and it worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

data1 = {
"Id": [1,2,3,4,5], 
"Data": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
}

data2 = {
"Id": [2,3,4,5,6], 
"Data": ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
}

data3 = {
"Id": [3,4,5,6,7], 
"Data": ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
}

data4 = {
"Id": [4,5,6,7,8], 
"Data": ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4)
```

Dataframes:

df1:

```
  Data  Id
0    a   1
1    b   2
2    c   3
3    d   4
4    e   5
```

df2:

```
  Data  Id
0    b   2
1    c   3
2    d   4
3    e   5
4    f   6
```

df3:

```
  Data  Id
0    c   3
1    d   4
2    e   5
3    f   6
4    g   7
```

df4:

```
  Data  Id
0    d   4
1    e   5
2    f   6
3    g   7
4    h   8
```

.

```
# define a counter variable to be used as a global
merged_count = 0

# define the function to be called via reduce
def merge_dfs(df_a, df_b):
    df = df_a.merge(df_b, on=['Id', 'Data'], how='outer')

    global merged_count
    merged_count += df_a.shape[0] + df_b.shape[0] - df.shape[0]
    return df

# use reduce function to get the final merged dataframe
df_final = reduce(merge_dfs, [df1, df2, df3, df4])

print(df_final)
print(merged_count)
```

df_final:

```
  Data  Id
0    a   1
1    b   2
2    c   3
3    d   4
4    e   5
5    f   6
6    g   7
7    h   8
```

Count of rows that got merged:

```
12
```

If this helps you, you can try to implement it on your scenario. 
In case there is a better way to achieve this, I would really like to know and also improve upon this solution, if required.

Comment: Thanks man I appreciate your effort! I pasted my tables so that it would be easier to understand what I meant.

Comment: The approach that I have suggested should work. You will have to change the function merge_dfs according to what you need (concat or join etc). IIUC the primary problem was how to get the counts of the merged rows, I guess my solution shows that already. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Ok, so I tried your approach and function print(merged_count) gives me -3962 so something is wrong

Comment: Sure. Ahh and I forgot to tell you that tables that I added to my post are merely a samples. Each dataframe has many many rows but I think it doesn't matter now. The output could be 3962 but of course not -3962.

Comment: I think I found the issue. The problem is that the keys on which you are trying to merge your dataframes are not primary key in at-least one of the dataframes. That is y the merge is getting into a Cartesian product and ending up with a resultant dataframes with significantly more rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214845/discussion-between-anshul-and-beginsql).